# How to change the code to show the number to a textbox instead in a div?

Tags: php, jquery

Using AJAX I display a number inside this DIV specsdiv using the jQuery code below.
However I am trying to display than number in the textbox so I can submit the number. I can not make it submit through the DIV, so how can I change my code to show it in the textbox?

Thank you

```
<div id="specsdiv">
    <input name="specs" type="text" value="45"/>
</div>
```

this is the jQuery code

```
function getSpecs(engineId) {
    var strURL = "findSpecs.php?engine=" + engineId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('specsdiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Amazingly, I don't see any jQuery code.

Comment: Give your input an id and use that instead of the div id

Comment: @ElefantPhace Why does it need an ID? `var $input = document.querySelectorAll('#specsdiv input');`

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any jQuery in use here and therefore I believe that there's a fundamental misunderstanding, so I'm going to supply pure javascript.

```
$input = document.querySelectorAll('#specsdiv input');
$input[0].value = req.responseText;
```

[And here is a jsFiddle simulation](http://jsfiddle.net/knY4R/) - please note that I have ommited the ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the input element using its name property and then update its value:

```
document.getElementsByName('specs')[0].value = req.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a class name to your textbox and count it using the following code

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="id_1" class="class_name" />
<input type="text" id="id_2" class="class_name" />
<input type="text" id="id_3" class="class_name" />
<input type="text" id="id_4" class="class_name" />
<input type="text" id="id_5" class="class_name" />
</div>
```

In javascript include jQuery and use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var total=$(".class_name").size();
     alert(total)

});
```

This will alert 5

Comment: Thank you for this, but can you be more specific? I am new to this and trying to edit an existing code